# Comparing 2 population proportions using significance tests

Tags: self-study, statistical-significance

> In a sample of 200 male drivers, 130 said they used seat belts. In a
>   sample of 300 female drivers, 163 said they used seat belts. Test the
>   claim that men are more safety conscious than women, at a significance
>   level 0.01. What will be your conclusion if you test whether there is
>   a gender difference for seat belt use at the same significance level?

So I've performed significance test and get z=4.32 => P-value<0.000317<0.01. Hence I can conclude that men are more safety conscious than women. I just don't understand the last question, say, 'What will be your conclusion if you test whether there is a gender difference for seat belt use at the same significance level?'. Any hint is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This looks like homework.  I've tagged it as such so you can get appropriate answers.  If it's not then you can remove the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second part of the question is asking about any difference, commonly called a 2-tailed test.  It's asking what the answer would be if the value for men could be higher or lower than women. The first question is more specific and a one-tailed test, that men are more safety conscious.